# How can I remove all containers running docker

Tags: docker

I want running containers to be stopped and removed.

```
PS C:\Users\Bayram Eren> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
8d8299ddb6bf   nginx          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes    80/tcp    con1
554971502a96   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   80/tcp    goofy_goldberg
PS C:\Users\Bayram Eren>

Docker container prune -f
```

Total reclaimed space: 0B
returns result

Why is this happening

Comment: `docker container prune` removes all *stopped* containers

Comment: this result returns Total reclaimed space: 0B

Comment: `docker kill $(docker ps -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` will kill all running containers and then remove any containers left in the system

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop your containers before removing them:

```
docker stop 8d8299ddb6bf   
docker stop 554971502a96
```

Or you can stop all running containers in one command

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q -f status=running)
```

Then you can call

```
docker container prune -f
```

Comment: I don't want to do it alone

Comment: I have edited my answer if you want to stop all your running containers with juste one line.

Comment: As far as I understand, the prune does not both stop and lift